# iptables: trying to understand rule giving access to synaptic

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

(This is for a system based on antiX, itself based on Debian stretch.)
I have the following rules for iptables:

```
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner root -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner internet_access -j ACCEPT
iptables -nvL
```

The idea is that external traffic is allowed for everything root does and for everything that's in a group called internet_access. This seems (mostly) to work as it should. However, synaptic (as well as the other programs in the apt family) does not seem to like that ruleset. It can't reload its databases and instead hangs. I googled for a solution and found that adding this line helps:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

I (think I) know what it does but I do not understand why it's necessary in the first place. synaptic runs as root and so it should have full internet access (other apps started as root do have internet access all right).

And second, if I change the rule above to this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m owner --uid-owner root -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

it stops working again. However, If I list the synaptic process with psgrep it is shown as user root and group root. I am puzzled.

(I am new to Linux (and even newer to iptables, so to speak) if you hadn't inferred that.)

Comment: A general information for you to consider, is that routingtables work from top to bottom, first found rule is the applied rule. That means if you have a rule, that drops all packages coming from 0.0.0.0 at the top, you won't ever get an incoming connection.

Comment: @NordlysJeger, a nitpick: those are not "routing tables" but are rather "netfilter tables" (or firewall rules, if you like). The routing subsystem is controlled by the `ip` command of the `iproute2` stack.

Comment: 1) How (exactly) do you run Synaptic? 2) Does it work if you run it via the `gksu` helper (it runs the specified program as root)? 3) if you just get a root shell, and run something like `apt update` there, does it succeed in fetching the package index files? The reason I'm asking is that we should try to discern the problem with your firewall rules from the problem with Synaptic.

Comment: @kostix I know, but the princip is the same

Comment: @NordlysJeger, that's beside the point. It does not matter whether you know it or not; what matters is not confusing newcomers.

Comment: True, for what it is worth, I'm sorry.

Comment: Nordlys Jeger's comment wasn't related to the question anyway. @kostix: Kamil's solution works but thanks for trying to help. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Kubuntu it's because `apt-get` runs multiple `/usr/lib/apt/methods/http` processes. Their owner is `_apt`, not `root`. I know `_apt` exists in my Debian as well.

<strike>Making `_apt` a member of your `internet_access` group should help.</strike>
Making `_apt` a member of your `internet_access` group won't help, because `--gid-owner` matches if the packet socket's file structure is owned by the given group. This is different than "if the packet socket's file structure is owned by a member of the given group".

In my Kubuntu these `http` processes run owned by `_apt`/`nogroup`. The easiest solution seems to simply allow `_apt` user to communicate:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner _apt -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That's it precisely. Thank you... one riddle (of many) solved:-/

Comment: That second thing is actually what I did after reading your solution. I like to keep this internet access stuff in one location...